# I am trying to concatenate checkboxes into an SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, concatenation

I have a very simple HTML form with POST method sending the name of certain activities which are checked or not...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="darts=1">Darts</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="e-darts=1">e-Darts</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="pool=1">Pool</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="snooker=1">Snooker</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="airhockey=1">Air Hockey</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="quizmachine=1">Quiz Machine</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" value="food=1">Food</input></br></br>
```

This isn't the problem, i'm getting the values through, all hunky dory.

I'm then trying to take from the array any checked values in a foreach loop and concatenate the values into the where clause by adding " and " in between all until the last one.  However, they are not concatenating and just outputting the final checkbox result - how can I concatenate?  This is my php code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if(!empty($_POST['games'])) {
    foreach($_POST['games'] as $check)  {
        if(++$i === count($_POST['games']))     {
            /*echo $check;*/
        }
        else    {
            $check = $check . " and ";
            /*echo $check;*/
        }
    }
}


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,         $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    foreach($conn->query("SELECT * from Establishments where town like '".$publocation."' and ".$check."") as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "</br>";

    }
    $conn = null;
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: what columns does `darts=1` and `e-darts=1` etc correspond to in your data?  It'll help to understand the data so the query can be correctly written

Comment: I put darts=1 so i could pull that through and use it in a concatenated SQL statement (i.e. select * from blah where darts=1 and e-darts=1, etc).

Comment: DB columns are just the value for the checkboxes without the "=1" part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`implode(' AND ', $_POST['games']);` would be a simpler way to do that.

The reason the way you're doing it is only getting the last value is that the `$check` variable is defined in the `foreach` loop, so it is recreated with each iteration.

Any approach that uses `$_POST` values directly in SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection, though.

Comment: Oh, I assumed those were boolean column names.

Comment: Not so sure if `e-darts` will work, may need back ticks for that.

Comment: i'll remove the hyphen from edarts, simplest way i suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

for concatenate checkbox use implode function
your code like below

```
$i = 0;
  if(!empty($_POST['games'])){ 
    $check=implode(' AND ',$_POST['games']);
    }
try 
  {
  $conn = newPDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
  $conn >setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  foreach($conn>query("SELECT * from Establishments where town like '".$publocation."' and ".$check."") as $row)
    { 
    print $row['name']</br>"; 
    }
$conn = null; 
  } 
catch (PDOException $e)
 {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
```

Thanks You